# Include ACE OLEDB 12 driver as part of a clickOnce install

Tags: c#, ms-access, clickonce, oledb

I have developed a C# winform application in Visual Studio 2010 that connects to a Access 2010 *.accdb database.  It works fine on my pc but when I install it on another, It throws the error "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
I tried to compile it to x86, as advised, without any succes.

Any help/advice is appreciated, I think that I should include this driver as part of my clickOnce install. If so, how do I do so? (It does not appear as an option in the checklist of requirements, in VS Properties > Publish > Previous requirements)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a more advanced method of deploying the necessary driver - ClickOnce won't do it by itself as far as I know. I also don't think it's as simple as a single DLL. The driver needs to register with the system etc.

There is a big issue with the Access drivers because of the way they are set up. If the user has Microsoft Office with Access installed, they will already have the ACE driver. The problem is, if they have 32 bit Access installed on a 64 bit machine, your 64 bit application will not be able to talk to Access because the machine only has a 32 bit driver, and you cannot install both.

If none of your users have Microsoft Office with Access, then you should be able to deploy the standalone driver installer for 32/64 bit as necessary with each computer.

Comment: Yes, I read about issues between 32/64 bit Access drivers. Up to me, it isn't really necesary to be a 64bit app, 32 will be fine too.
How I can deploy the application so it can detect / install the correct driver on the user's system, as necessary?

Comment: That all depends on which installer method you go with. Something like InnoSetup has some scripting capabilities to check for certain registry keys (find out which ones are associated with the ACE driver) and performs certain tasks if they are not found. I believe that the NSIS software can handle the same thing - but I find InnoSetup to be easier to use with the InnoIDE.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include arbitrary assemblies and files as part of your ClickOnce install by adding them to the project and changing their file type to Content. They will then appear in the list of Application Files.

Note that you'll get a warning from Visual Studio if you do this, but it can be safely ignored.

Comment: I think that way the file is copied to the local machine, but will not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an msi instead of oneclick and create a custom action that would install ace driver in quiet mode. Since its an executable you can just run it in a process object